# Android: Using multiple databases or using single database?

Tags: android, database

In many cases there are many tables in the android application, some of the tables are not related closely, should I separate them into multiple databases?

As i know, splitting into multi-databases avoid locking each other, and the side effect is it's more complex to management for more than one SQLiteDatabase or ContentProvider, is it right?

Any other principles?

Answer (score 0):

You will have locking issues only when multiple threads in your app try to write to db simultaneously.

So using multiple databases makes sense only if

a) you have more than one thread writing to db and

b) different threads write to different set of tables. (thread 1 writes ONLY to tables A,B and C and thread 2 writes only to table D and E)